# Yajra Datatables append variable amount of custom columns to rows

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

guys,

We have an application (running laravel 5.2 + php5.6), and one of its many features involves stock control, via a series of reports.

Anyway, one of the components of this reporting system involves showing a datatable, in which the app reflects quarterly consumption of stocks.

E.g.:

```
Stock | Q1-2019 | Q2-2019 | Q3-2019

A     | 1203    | 1500    | 1345
```

Thing is, both the stocks, as well as the date range, are variable.

This means a simple query just won't cut it (afaik. Please correct me if I'm wrong). 
So in some way, I must get the stocks, and for each item, calculate the quarterly usage.

The way I've solved this thus far is as follows (pseudo-codish.):

```
    $stocks = Stock::select([
        'id',
        'name'
      ])->get();

    $stocks->each(function ($item) use ($date_from, $date_to) {
      $item->totals = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT
        YEAR(stock_used.use_date) as year,
        QUARTER(stock_used.use_date) as quarter,
        CONCAT(QUARTER(stock_used.use_date), 'Q-', YEAR(stock_used.use_date)) as identifier,

        SUM(stock_used.quantity) as quantity

        FROM stock_used

        WHERE stock_used.use_date BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'
        AND stock_used.status = 'used'
        AND stock_used.stock_id = {$item->id}

        GROUP BY quarter,year
      "));

      return $item;
    });


    return Datatables::of($stocks)
      ->filter(function ($query) {
          $searchterm = request()->input('filter');

          if ($searchterm) {
              $query->where('name', 'like', "%" . $filter . "%");
          }
      })
      ->make(true);
  }
```

Problem: This iterates over the entire table, this is okay-ish, for now, and has allowed me to meet my deadline, but it can turn load times into a lovecraftian nightmare way too easily.

Instead, since I KNOW that the Yajra Datatables module is using pagination, I'd like to tell it to perform the query above for each element in the data that is going to be actually served(i.e. the current page, instead of the entire table.)

Thank you very much in advance, guys.

Comment: What you need to do to take advantage of pagination is pass a QueryBuilder object to `DataTables::of()`. Update your question with your tables and model relationships, and it's likely someone will be able to see a better way of pulling this data than a raw query.

Comment: The actual relationship spans easily 8 or 9 tables, it's simplified here in order to explain the issue. I cannot do it in my initial Eloquent query because it could be that I have data for only one quarter, all quarters, or the clients request may span 20 years or 2 years or only 1 quarter, so it seems difficult to do if not impossible. Also yeah trust me seeing the actual relationships it's really waaayyyy easier to do a raw query.

Comment: My question was more along the lines of how do I do that  code that now resides in my each... inside of my datatable. not before. Being able to append the result of my monster query as a custom field containing the resulting array to every row of the result will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what I described does exist. 
The solution is roughly as follows (remember this is simplified because my actual query is easily around 60 lines but if you're struggling with a similar problem, you'll hopefully get the picture.):

```
  return Datatables::of($materiales)
      ->addColumn('totals', function(Stock $stock) use ($date_from, $date_to) {
        return DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT
          YEAR(stock_used.use_date) as year,
          QUARTER(stock_used.use_date) as quarter,
          CONCAT(QUARTER(stock_used.use_date), 'Q-', YEAR(stock_used.use_date)) as identifier,

          SUM(stock_used.quantity) as quantity

          FROM stock_used

          WHERE stock_used.use_date BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'
          AND stock_used.status = 'used'
          AND stock_used.stock_id = {$stock->id}

          GROUP BY quarter,year
        "));
      })

      ->filter(function ($query) {
        $searchterm = request()->input('stockFilter');

        if ($searchterm) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%" . $searchterm . "%");
        }
      })
      ->make(true);
```